# Java Images not drawn when running java -jar

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem i have never had before and couldnt find a solution on the web.
I have a small Programm which uses some images to print a menu.

This is the Class i use to print the Images:

```
public class ViewImage extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Image image = null;

    public ViewImage(int x, int y, String path) {
        this(x, y, new ImageIcon(path).getImage());
    }

    public ViewImage(int x, int y, Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        this.setBounds(x, y, image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int x = ((this.getWidth() - image.getWidth(null)) / 2);
        int y = ((this.getHeight() - image.getHeight(null)) / 2);

        g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    }

    public void setImage(String path) {
        this.image = new ImageIcon(path).getImage();
    }
 }
```

My Images are all part of the classpath an i call them with:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MyImage.png").getPath()
```

Works fine until i package my programm into a jar file and run 
it from console with:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

My programm starts well but no image are printed. No Exceptions, no Errors, 
nothing.

What can cause such an behaviour?

Comment: It could be the location of MyImage.png in the jar-file. Could you unzip the jar-file, and provide a listing of its directory structure?

Comment: My Images are all in the root directory when i unpack my jar next to the source-folder and the META-INF

Comment: Cannot you use `getResourceAsStream` instead of trying to get to an actual file?

Comment: @MarcTigges : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). Hopefully it might be able to help you too :-) The way you using 'ImageIcon`, it is bound to silently do away with any alarms, that the code might encounter :-) Last link in that post will definitely help you, if you doing it without an IDE :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before all be sure your resource is correctly loaded (for example with a System.out())!

Instead to use `ImageIcon(String location)` use `ImageIcon(URL location)` constructor because your image is not on hdd, but live compressed as URL in your classpath (something like MyJar.jar!/path/to/image.png"); you have to modify your image loading as

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MyImage.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

The ".getPath()" part of your code excludes the leading part of the URL.
This needs to be present if your resource is part of a jar file.

I suggest you remove the ".getPath()" and use the full URL.
Printing out the full URL is a good idea too, in a System.out.println for example.