# Can't load image - image not found

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource, bufferedimage

I am trying to load an image as part of my platformer, but it cant seam to find the image, I put it into the default package, which is the same as the class

```
public BufferedImage loadImage() {
  try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("level.jpg"));
    System.out.println("Level Found!");
    return img;

  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Level Missing!");
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you paste your Stacktrace here??

Comment: Is file correctly deployed in your classpath?

Comment: try providing the absolute path ....

Comment: Often it's better to get your resources such as images as, well, as resources.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250236/java-images-not-drawn-when-running-java-jar/18250364#18250364

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 3):

If you reference your files like this `new File("level.jpg")` you have to put those files into the current directory. In most cases it's not the default package directory.

For example using Eclipse your typical directory structure would be like this:

```
+ MyProject
  |
  + src
    |
    + org/mypackage1
    + org/mypackage2
```

In order to get `new File("level.jpg")` to work you have to put `level.jpg` into the project root directory, like this

```
+ MyProject
  |
  + src
  | |
  | + org/mypackage1
  | + org/mypackage2
  |
  + level.jpg
```

Comment: You mean the src directory instead of project root

Comment: I meant project root. Src directory is the default package. Just click `edit` button below the answer to see the "source code". It's very easy to draw such ascii graphics :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use get resource method of the class loader

Comment: Yours is a good suggestion -- can you expand on it a bit more by providing a little more detail for the original poster's benefit?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Good point.  I added a comment that says much the same thing, but is more detailed than this entire answer!