# FileInputStream look into root of Jar

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream

I have a FileInputStream in a class in the package com.nishu.ld28.utilities, and I want to access sound files in the folder Sounds, which is not in the com.nishu.ld28 package. I specify the path for loading like so:

```
"sounds/merry_xmas.wav"
```

And then try to load it like this:

```
new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))
```

When I export the jar, the command line prompt that I run it through says it can't find the file. I know how to access the files when I am running the program in Eclipse, but I can't figure out how to point the FileInputStream to the Sounds folder when I export it.

Edit: As requested, here's my code:

```
public void loadSound(String path)  {
    WaveData data = null;
    data = WaveData.create(GameSound.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
    int buffer = alGenBuffers();
    alBufferData(buffer, data.format, data.data, data.samplerate);
    data.dispose();
    source = alGenSources();
    alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);
}
```

WaveData accepts an InputStream or other types of IO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250236/java-images-not-drawn-when-running-java-jar/18250364#18250364

Comment: What am I supposed to do with that? FileInputStream doesn't accept a InputStream.

Comment: Is the `sounds/merry_xmas.wav` embedded in your jar ?

Comment: Things like this have been asked many times. Please search before asking.

Comment: My question is different though, I'm using OpenAL, not just standard file IO.

Comment: That does not make any difference. Adding a leading slash has been suggested many times to many similar questions and you didn't try it before asking, did you?

Comment: Uh yes I did, but for some reason WaveData does not act normally after exporting. I know what I'm talking about, I've been trying to debug this for the past two days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the `com.nishu.ld28.utilities` in the same package of your class , let's call it **MyClass**.

**Your package:**

[image]

**Your code:**

```
package com.nishu.ld28.utilities;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class MyClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("sound/merry_xmas.wav");

      System.out.format("is is null ? => %s", is==null);
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
is is null ? => false
```

Comment: But com.nishu.ld28.utilities is a package containing the class that I am trying to load the Sound files with?

Comment: @opiop65 For Java it's not a problem. You can have both the sound and the class located in the same package. The sound is actually seen as a resource.

Comment: There's no need prefix the name of a resource with the package name of the class the needs it

Comment: Oh never mind, I thought you were trying to say that com.nishu.ld28 was a class.

Comment: That's fine. So then I can just call my resources like this?: merry_xmas.wav

Comment: @opiop65 You can, have look at the picture in my answer.

Comment: And this will work after exporting too? Edit: Didn't work after exporting!

Comment: The wav file is found relatively to the class, so it'll work after exporting.

Comment: Well it didn't :P It threw an NPE at this line:   alBufferData(buffer, data.format, data.data, data.samplerate);
Which takes the file I just loaded as the data. So the WaveData is never found.

Comment: @opiop65 I don't use `getClassLoader` in my sample code, check that buffer is not null, check that the path variable is correctly set.

Comment: I checked that all of those aren't null already... thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `FileInputStream`, because you aren't reading from the filesystem. Use the `InputStream` returned by [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String res)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or `Class.getResourceAsStream(String res)`. So either

```
in = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("sounds/merry_xmas.wav");
```

or

```
in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/merry_xmas.wav");
```

Note the leading slash in the second example.