# properties file is not called while creating the jar

Tags: java, jar

I have created a java project in which I am using a properties file also which is created inside a java packgae named abcedf

so package name is abcdef which consists a class name abc.java and a property file named drg.properties ,now from class abc.java i am referring to that properties file as..

```
abc tt = new abc();
URL url = tt.getClass().getResource("./drg.properties");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
```

now this file is referred and my program runs successfully but when I am trying to make it executable jar then this property file is not referred
please advise what is went wrong while creating the property file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250236/java-images-not-drawn-when-running-java-jar/18250364#18250364
Use URL.openStream() instead of new File()!

Comment: Please use proper Java naming conventions so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: @bellabax can you please explain in detail so that I can grasp.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
tt.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./drg.properties");
```

to access the property file inside a JAR. You will get an `InputStream` as returned object.

-------------------------------------------------
Here is an example to load the `InputStream` to `Properties` object

```
InputStream in = tt.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./drg.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(in); // Loads content into properties object
in.close();
```

If your case, you can directly use, the `InputStream` instead of using `FileInputStream`

Comment: dARKpRINCE Thanks, can you also please explain in details  about input stream object also

Comment: I have edited the answer to add an example. If this helped, please accept this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you access "jarred" resource you can't access it directly as you access a resource on your HDD with `new File()` (because resource doesn't live uncompressed on your drive) but you have to access resource (stored in your application jar) using [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Code will looks like (with java7 [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature)

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try(InputStream is = tt.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./drg.properties")) { 
 p.load(is); // Loads content into p object
}
```